# Tomcat starting only through cmd

Tags: tomcat8

I have installed tomcat 8 and set its environment variable CATALINA_HOME and added it to PATH. I could start tomcat but only through cmd. When I directly go inside bin directory of tomcat and click on startup windows batch file tomcat is not starting. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I should be able to start tomcat either way